# How do I parse my JSON with external middleware now that Express doesn't carry a body parser?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, express

How do I parse my JSON with external middleware now that Express doesn't carry a body parser?

For a while, I was using Express bodyParser to receive and respond to JSON posts to the server. Each time I started up the server, express said something about bodyParser being removed soon, and sure enough, I've updated and now JSON requests seem to be showing null.

So I didn't understand how middleware worked, and had followed an express tutorial to use the body parser. Now, using separate body parser middleware, it seems I'm doing it wrong.

Before, my syntax was:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Now, with the module [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) as middleware, it's like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And an example as a whole:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

function listen() {

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        console.log('User ' + username + ' is attempting login...');
        validate(username, password, function (err, result) {

            if (err) loginFail(req, res, err);
            else loginSucceed(req, res, result);

        });
    });

    app.listen(3333);

}

listen();
```

I tried `express.json()` as the middleware, but that triggers the fatal error:

> ```
> Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express
> and must be installed separately. Please see
> https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
> ```

That link leads to the [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) that I'm using via `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.

---

Update:

Using `bodyParser.json()` results in no error, but the data values are null:

> User undefined is attempting login...

My client code should be fine, but here it is for completeness:

```
function sendLogin() {

    popLogCreds(creds);

    var loginCredentials = {

        "username": creds.username,
            "password": creds.password

    };

    console.log("Sending login credentials: " + 
    JSON.stringify(loginCredentials, null, 4));

    request = $.ajax({

        url: "http://54.186.131.77:3333/login",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: loginCredentials,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {

            postError("Uh Oh! The Officeball server is down.");

        },
        success: function (data) {

            var ParsedData = data;

            sessionStorage.username = creds.username;
            sessionStorage.password = creds.password;
            sessionStorage.fname = ParsedData.fname;
            sessionStorage.lname = ParsedData.lname;
            sessionStorage.rank = ParsedData.rank;

            console.log(sessionStorage);

            window.location.replace("app.html");

        }

    });

}
```

Which results in:

> ```
> Sending login credentials: {
>     "username": "jonathan@evisiion.com",
>     "password": "J******!"
> }
> ```

And then the result is the POST's error output, which is, as above:

> ```
> error : function () {
>                   postError("Uh Oh! The Officeball server is down.");
>               }
> ```

Don't take that error message literally. Just means an error happened. The server is, in fact, getting that request, as shown up above.

Comment: Your code seems fine, are you sure you're  sending the data with the right headers

Comment: Are you getting some particular error now with `bodyParser.json()`? Do you have an example with real code? Your example doesn't even define `app` so it clearly isn't real.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am not getting an error.. It's just giving me null data: `User undefined is attempting login...` -- I will have another look at the client side, but it's been working there for weeks, only change being Express's update to 4.5.1. Also, I have updated my code to be real, up to the point of validation, which is not included.

Comment: @jt0dd Can you provide an example of the request to `POST /login`? What format of data is being sent in the request? The `express.bodyParser()` middleware was previously a bundle of `json()`, `urlencoded()`, and `multipart()` middleware. And, only 2 of those remain with [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski working on providing that code now.

Comment: @jt0dd Pulled my answer as it doesn't address the problem at hand. looking over your code now. Thanks for supplying it!

Comment: @m.casey Thanks for your time. I try to provide only what code is necessary to keep the question short,but sometimes more must be shown.

Comment: I just use - app.use(bodyParser());

Comment: @Dylan don't plan on using it for very long. `bodyParser()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `$.ajax()` sends `data` [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as mentioned in the description of the [`processData` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

The `body-parser` that corresponds to that `Content-Type` and format is [`urlencoded()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions):

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

---

If you'd rather use JSON for the request, you'll need to provide the `data` already formatted as such along with a matching `contentType` that `bodyParser.json()` recognizes:

```
request = $.ajax({

    url: "http://54.186.131.77:3333/login",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(loginCredentials),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'

    // ...
});
```

Note for cross-domain: With these modifications, the server will have to handle [preflight `OPTIONS` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for the route.

---

And, note that a `bodyParser` isn't needed for `HEAD` or `GET` requests as the `data` is included in the URL rather than the body. Express parses that separately into `req.query`.

Comment: I think the OP rather wants to use `data: JSON.stringify(loginCredentials), contentType: 'application/json'`, but you're right: +1

Comment: Do I need to use both `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());` and `app.use(bodyParser.json());`?

Comment: @jt0dd If you want to support both request formats, yeah. If you target one and ensure it's always the one used in requests, then you'll only need the one matching body-parser. They each act based on the value of the `Content-Type` request header and shouldn't conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

In your node code,

make sure you put these two lines of code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

......then your other code follows..
enjoy...